# Travel insurance to USA

Tags: usa, health, insurance

I am planning to travel to USA for a short stay, around 2 months. I think it will be better to buy a little travel insurance in case I feel sick or anything. However, I have no idea about where to buy it. Do you have any piece of advice for my case about how to get an insurance?

Comment: As you're not new, you've read the [faq] and you've probably just forgotten that asking for recommendations / polling is not a good fit.  I'd highly recommend rephrasing before it gets closed to better fit the site, or if it's already been closed when you see it - edit and flag to reopen.

Comment: Where do you live?

Answer (score 3):

Travel health insurance is not just "better", it is *absolutely vital*, especially when travelling to the USA with its notoriously expensive medical system. Seriously: if you don't get insurance and any health crisis happens, it could very easily leave you in debt that takes years to get out of. A broken leg that requires surgery will [cost up to 35,000 dollars](http://health.costhelper.com/broken-leg.html)!

Fortunately, travel health insurance is relatively cheap and easy to get. Just ask your regular health insurance provider at home, they probably have an offer. Travel agents also often have such offers (they get a commission from the insurer).

Answer (score 2):

I live in the U.S., and my employer provides excellent health insurance for me (which follows me around the world), so I have never had a reason to buy traveler's health insurance in the U.S. or anywhere.  So I cannot recommend any specific company or policy (and it would be off-topic to do so even if I could), but google found a few options for you:

1. [HTH Travel Insurance](http://www.hthtravelinsurance.com/) has a few options.
2. [International Medical Group](http://www.imglobal.com/img-insurance/travel-medical-insurance.aspx)
3. [MEDEX](http://www.medexassist.com/)

I'm sure Google can find many more options, if one of these doesn't suit your needs.

Whether you can buy these policies may also depend on where you live.  And there may be additional options available to you locally through a travel agent or local insurance company.  But since I don't know where you live, I can't really address that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to the USA for tourism, then the cheapest option will probably be a travel insurance, that covers medical costs as well. These things work differently in different countries, but here in the UK there are lots of options (you can use Google, etc.). Remember to make sure that

- Your insurance covers the USA, often this is an optional extra on the policy
- That your insurance covers the whole period when you are abroad (2 months is regarded as a rather long tourist trip by most insurance companies)
- The excess, maximum level of cover, existing conditions, etc. - these are all the things you should check in the small print as well.

If you are traveling for work purposes, then I think your employer should sort your insurance (I am not an expert here though) - so ask them first.