# Travel Insurance for my parents visiting the U.S

Tags: usa, health, insurance

My parents are visiting the U.S. and are planning on staying for a few months. I was wondering what are some of the (**reputable** /**trustworthy**) health insurance companies in the U.S. that can provide travel Insurance for someone who is visiting the U.S.

F.Y.I.: I want to purchase the insurance for them in the U.S. because I can do all the paper work for them from U.S. instead of trying to call some guy/company overseas. So, please don't recommend buying insurance from their home country.
I also found this link on [stackexchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16847/travel-insurance-to-usa/16853#16853) but it does not specify which one of these companies are actually trustworthy/reputable companies (same problem I have when I Google ). So, please when you respond share with me the name of companies you have used or know someone that used before and was happy with them.

just to add more clarification and eliminate generating endless responses based on opionon...If the company is BBB accredited then it's good enough.

http://www.bbb.org/search/

Comment: Is this with the intent of preparing some sort of long-stay visa ?

Comment: three to four months.

Comment: How do you measure "trustworthiness"?  Personal anecdotes are almost useless here, because the worth of an insurance is only tested when you need it.

Comment: let's not get very picky....trustworthiness is as I described....is if you or someone you know has used the insurance and was happy with them.

Comment: @CPU100 It's very difficult to assess over satisfaction with any big organization: they employ a mix of people, have policies or products beloved by some and despised by others, and generate experiences that depend a lot on circumstances and what you want or need from them at a particular time (e.g. "*Loved* the dental coverage, *hated* the approved pancreatic cancer medications..."). The "bad" company may be the "best" for you sometimes: I just had to hold my nose and open a Comcast account for my company, because despite CMCSA's horrible reputation, the competition couldn't compete.

Comment: @jpatokal I modified the question to be more clear, if they are accredited BBB http://www.bbb.org/search/ then it's good enough for me.